# Batch file variable echoing variable name and not contained text

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, for-loop

I am relatively new to batch files, here is what I am trying to do:

1. I have a folder containing several csv files named:

   ```
   Thu_Oct_26_11-12-07_BST_2017+testa.csv
   Thu_Oct_26_11-12-07_BST_2017+testb.csv
   ```

   text in the file is `|` separated i.e.

   ```
   Peg|Adoption|Indonesia|1980|
   Peg|Adoption|Indonesia|1981|
   ```
2. I have a batch code that puts the filename at the front of each row in the csv file

   ```
   ::add filename
   for /f %%a in ('dir /b ^"C:\Temp\CSV\Countries\*.csv^"'
   ) do (
   for /f "tokens=*" %%b in (%%a
   ) do echo %%a^|%%b >> "C:\Temp\CSV\Countries\import_temp\%%a")
   pause
   ```
3. The above works to add the entire name to the front of the rows, but I only want to add the date part of the filename to the row.  I tried selecting a substring from `%%a` using `:~0,10` but this still pastes the whole string

   ```
   ::add filename
   for /f %%a in ('dir /b ^"C:\Temp\CSV\Countries\*.csv^"'
   ) do (
   for /f "tokens=*" %%b in (%%a
   ) do echo %%a:~0,10^|%%b >> "C:\Temp\CSV\Countries\import_temp\%%a")
   pause
   ```

   I have also tried setting a new variable equal to `%%a` substring but this prints `%c` instead of the first part of the file name

   ```
   ::add filename
   for /f %%a in ('dir /b ^"C:\Temp\CSV\Countries\*.csv^"'
   ) do (
   set c=%%a:~0,10
   for /f "tokens=*" %%b in (%%a
   ) do echo %%c^|%%b >> "C:\Temp\CSV\Countries\import_temp\%%a")
   pause
   ```

Is anyone able to indicate what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need [delayed environment variable expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) inside body of __FOR__ loop. And string substitution works only with __environment__ variables, but not with __loop__ variables. `a`  referenced with `%%a` is a __loop__ variable. Run in a command prompt window `set /?` and `for /?` and read entire output help for both commands. BTW: `^` is not needed left to `"`. And `for %%a in ("C:\Temp\CSV\Countries\*.csv") do (` can be also used here without execution of __DIR__ in a separate command process in background.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
MD "%sourcedir%\import_temp" 2>NUL
::add filename
for /f %%a in ('dir /b "%sourcedir%\*.csv"'
) do (
 for /f "tokens=1-3delims=_" %%B in ("%%a"
 ) do echo %%B_%%C_%%D^|%%a >> "%sourcedir%\import_temp\%%a"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I added an `md` to force-generate the `import_temp` subdirectory. The `2>nul` serves to suppress complaints that the directory already exists.

I changed the case of the metavariable used in the inner loop for distinction purposes. Analysing the string `%%a` into tokens using `_` as a delimiter and selecting the first 3 tokens assigns each substring from `%%a` into `%%B`...`%%D`, so all that's required is to re-assemble the date and concatenate that with `%%a` which contains the filename alone. Note that the metavariable of a `for` loop is one of the few places where `cmd` is case-sensitive.

The carets to escape `"` in the `dir` are not required.

Comment: thanks, this works, as does ::add filename
for /f %%a in ('dir /b "C:\Temp\CSV\Countries\*.csv"'
) do (
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set c=%%a
set c=!c:~0,28!
for /f "tokens=*" %%b in (%%a
) do (
echo !c!^|%%b >> "C:\Temp\CSV\Countries\import_temp\%%a"))
pause